# WPF copying wrap panel

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

How do I copy WrapPanel?

I have window in which I have WrapPanel with some controls inside. I'd like to copy it inside my code so I would have 2 or more exact looking panels on the same window but with different names for controls.

This is how my XAML looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="498">
        <WrapPanel x:Name="Wrap1" Height="142" Margin="0,0,345.6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152">
            <Button x:Name="wrap1_button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <Button x:Name="wrap1_button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <Label x:Name="wrap1_label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I would like to get another WrapPanel placed next to first one, named Wrap2 with controls inside wrap2_button, wrap2_button1, wrap2_label.

I tried inserting it in StackPanel and doing something like that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WrapPanel Wrap2 = Wrap1;
        stackPanel.Children.Add(Wrap2);
    }
}
```

but it doesnt work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you will have to create another `WrapPanel`, add it to the `StackPanel`, and add children to the second `WrapPanel`.

Now, if your reaction is to recoil from the duplication, that is a good instinct. This may be a good use case for a `UserControl` which is a way to bundle groups of standard WPF controls to allow for their reuse.

What I would suggest is to create a new `UserControl` which is a `WrapPanel` with the children you have, then add 2 instances of that new `UserControl` to the `StackPanel` in your window.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) is a link to the Remarks of the `UserControl` class with some of the considerations of creating your own custom controls.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.